# Cannot import any android packges in flutter project

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to write some native codes in flutter, but i cant import any android packages in my MainActivity, see the image below:

[MainActivity.java: THIS IS HOW MY IMPORTS ARE, PLEASE SEE THIS IMAGE TO UNDERSTAND](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN2DJ.png)

I cant import any native package, anyone can help me please?

Flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```